# name objects from vector values

Tags: r, object, naming

I'm trying to use the character values of a vector to name new objects and then make those new objects into new matrices. So if I have the following vector:

```
Named <- c("a", "b", "c")
```

I want to be have a loop to make objects named "a", "b", and "c"

```
for(i in 1:length(Named)){
Named[i] <- matrix(0L, nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
}
```

I realize that this code currently inputs data into the vector. How do I extract the characters at Named[i] to use as the name of the new objects?

So that the loop does the same thing as writing this code:

```
a <- matrix(0L, nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
b <- matrix(0L, nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
c <- matrix(0L, nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) assign** Normally one would want to assign the values into a list but if you must assign them into the global environment then this is a good application for a `for` loop:

```
for(nm in Named) assign(nm, matrix(0L, 3, 3), .GlobalEnv)
```

If you are already doing this at the global environment level then you could optionally omit the last argument to `assign`.

**2) index global environment** This would also work:

```
for(nm in Named) .GlobalEnv[[nm]] <- matrix(0L, 3, 3)
```

**3) list2env** Another approach is to create a list then use `list2env` to copy its components to the global environment.

```
list2env( Map(function(x) matrix(0L, 3, 3), Named), .GlobalEnv )
```

**4) hard coding** Note that if you just have a few elements to assign and you don't need to parameterize by a variable such as `Named` you could just hard code it like this:

```
a <- b <- c <- matrix(0L, 3, 3)
```

**5) list** If in the end you do decide to create a list instead of objects in the global environment then:

```
L <- Map(function(x) matrix(0L, 3, 3), Named)
```